# Start Process with arguments

Tags: string, powershell

I am trying to create a script that would allow users to start an online repair of Office, I am checking if they have 32 or 64 bits then the language.

I made the following script but nothing happens and I don't know why

```
$culture = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration)."ClientCulture"
$platform = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration)."Platform"

$CMD = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe"

Start-Process -FilePath $CMD -ArgumentList @("scenario=Repair", "platform=$platform", "culture=$culture", "forceappshutdown=True", "RepairType=FullRepair", "DisplayLevel=True") -Wait
```

Comment: Check the contents of your temp directory -- you should find a file of the form `[machine]-[yyyyMMdd]-[nnnn].log` that contains details. One obvious problem might be that you're not running the script/command elevated; telltale sign of this is operations failing with error 5 (access denied). Try passing `-Verb Runas` to `Start-Process`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, indeed I am not local admin on my test machine, the script works in an elevated PS console